# Imported video mp4 not render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

A video in MP4 imported in Blender  doesn't  work. I can  see the video in the preview, but when I render it, it is transformed in a single image.

**UPDATE**
I create new project, select camera and then drag&drop .MP4 video on scene.
I create new 3d object that rotate in front of MP4 video layer.

3d object render correctly but video not play.
Only in preview mode, video play correctly.

Comment: Can you add details to your question? Like how did you import the mp4, as a plane or a sequence in the VSE or in the compositor or what?

Comment: @wilks I update question

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your output information is set to an image output.  You need to change it to a video output in the properties panel (see image below).  Then hit Render > Render Animation.

[image: RenderAnimation]

You also may need to change some audio settings, which I would need to research to remember how.